# Ограничение внешнего ключа

Tags: mysql

Подскажите почему не могу удалить запись из таблицы Departments?

```
Organizations
----------------
id - PK

Departments
----------------
id
org_id - FK

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`emedia_backend`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `FK_dep_id` FOREIGN KEY (`dep_id`) REFERENCES `departments` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Answer (score 3):

Судя по тексту ошибки

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`emedia_backend`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `FK_dep_id`
  FOREIGN KEY (`dep_id`) REFERENCES `departments` (`id`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

У вас есть, не указанная в вопросе таблица `users` и в ней есть запись с удаляемым департаментом. Сначала удалите пользователей или поставите им другой dep_id или сделайте его NULL.

Так же можно изменить ваш foreign key и дать ему действие по умолчанию `on delete cascade` для автоматического удаления записей из таблицы `users` при удалении `departments` с которыми они связаны или `on delete set null` для установки их dep_id в NULL.

Comment: Точно не заметил( Спасибо

Comment: Ну по поводу cascade знаю,в данной ситуации мне не нужно удалять записи из дочерней таблицы,а вот второй вариант подойдет